# Launch an activity to view photo

Tags: android

I am using the following code to launch an activity to view a photo, can i configure to launch it in a landscape mode or a portrait mode?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(photoUri, type);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Thank you.

Comment: This post should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434071/gracefully-handling-screen-orientation-change-during-activity-start

Comment: @Stephan I think the answers in this post assume that the writer is in control of (as in he created the activities) in question. Michael it seems is displaying his image in an activity that he did not create, and thus can't control the manifest of. Michael I think your only option is to create the activity that you are showing the image in and use the techniques found in this link from Stephan.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control over the Activity that is launched by the intent then you have to contact the developer of the launched activity to find out. Its possible that you could attach an extra that would specify the preferred orientation but without knowing which Activity launches as the result of your intent its impossible to say.

Why not develop your own photoviewer? That will give you complete control over the orientation.